# get "jump to column" behavior of fundamental mode in a major mode

Tags: key-bindings, indentation

I noticed that when in `fundamental-mode` or `prog-mode` (basically any mode without an `indent-line-function`) the `TAB` key will jump between columns. For example if I have

```
foo   bar   baz
fot   bat|
```

with the cursor at the `|` and I hit `TAB` it will move my cursor to align with `baz`.

```
foo   bar   baz
fot   bat   |
```

This is really nice when doing something like adding ports to a port list in Verilog. However in `verilog-mode` (and every other programming major mode I have tested) hitting `TAB` will just indent the line.

My question is, what is this `fundamental-mode` mechanism called and how can I add it to another major mode?

Comment: Start by seeing what the `<tab>` key is bound to in `fundamental-mode`, using `C-h k`.

Comment: It’s bound to `indent-for-tab-command` in both cases

Comment: I misspoke, they are bound to different commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that when in ... any mode without an `indent-line-function` ... the TAB key will jump between columns.

I think you've noticed and ignored the answer to your own question.

Those modes are *not* "without an `indent-line-function`".  In fact if you were to set `indent-line-function` to `nil` you would trigger an error.

In those modes `indent-line-function` is set to **`indent-relative`** -- which is the function that provides the behaviour you're looking for.

So to make another major mode behave the same way, you could use its mode hook to set that value:

```el
(add-hook 'foo-mode-hook 'my-foo-mode-hook)

(defun my-foo-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `foo-mode' behaviours."
  (setq-local indent-line-function 'indent-relative))
```

That won't necessarily do the trick, mind (depending on the mode, TAB might not result in `indent-line-function` ever being used), so you can always fall back to something like:

```el
(defun my-foo-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `foo-mode' behaviours."
  (local-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'indent-relative))
```

Comment: As you suspected, setting the `indent-line-function` did not do anything. `verilog-mode` rebinds the `TAB` key to another function. However that was easy to override and gave me the behavior that I wanted. Thanks!